# I need help in creating OSPF between MultiLayerSwitch and Routers in packet tracer

Tags: switch, router, ospf

I know we cannot create OSPF with different subnets. What network addresses should I put in the MLS and R1 to make it adjacent?

Here's the configuration for **MLS**:

```
interface FastEthernet0/15
 no switchport
 ip address 10.1.100.1 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto 
!
router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 10.1.100.1 0.0.0.0 area 0 !
```

End of configurations for MLS

**R1**

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.1.100.2 255.255.255.0
! 
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 10.1.100.2 0.0.0.0 area 0
```

[image: OSPF network]

Comment: You should use the two available addresses on the link between them. I really do not understand the problem. If you really want help, you should include the device configurations.

Comment: First of all, please check reachability. The R1 interface FastEthernet0/0 mask is 24 bits. `ip address 10.1.100.2 255.255.255.0` If 30 bits are a correct IP address, set as follows. `10.1.100.2 255.255.255.252`

Comment: As was pointed out in the previous comment, your masks do not match, and the router mask does not agree with the diagram. Also, You really need to include the full configurations because you leave us guessing if you enabled routing in the layer-3 switch.

Comment: Mask on interfaces should be equal `/30` or `/24` on both sides. And I would set proper wildcards for `network` statement in OSPF router configuration: `0.0.0.255` for `/24` or `0.0.0.3` for `/30`.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces Fa0/15 on MLS and Fa 0/0 on R1 do not have the same subnet mask.  In order for routers to become adjacent neighbors, they must have the same subnet mask.